# Which distance to be used for object distance, in mirror formula?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, geometric-optics

I know that mirror formula is, $$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{u}$$ but there's a doubt in the following case,[image]

Here to solve the problem, what value should i put for *u* in mirror formula, *u*<sub>1</sub> ( The distance of the virtual object from pole ) or *u*<sub>2</sub> ( The distance of the real object from the pole ) ?

Comment: Constructively speaking, It seems you have not studied the proofs behind these formulae, Learning those will help you get better insights of how and why are terms defined the way they are...

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Yes you are right, can you recommend a source where that is available because the source from where i study have skipped the parts you are mentioning

Comment: https://phys.libretexts.org/  might be a great resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use $u_2$ as the object distance because you forgot the definition of object, it is the **point** of intersection of incident rays and the object corresponding to $u_2$ don't seems to me a point

Answer (score 1):

*u* is the object distance (it can be for both virtual and real objects)and *v* is for image distance from the pole(again can be for virtual and real images)
image is formed at the point of intersection of reflected rays.
as per the figure the *u*=*u2* and *v* will be:
[image]

Comment: But here virtual object is also present, so why you have chosen real object for distance ?

Comment: but the silvering of the mirror is on the other side, I have updated my answer.

Comment: here both virtual and real object are present